# Transferring variables from one activity to a database

Tags: android, database, android-intent

```
package nidhin.survey;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String TABLE = "mygrades";
static final String NAME = "name";
static final String VALUE = "value";

DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, "grades.sqlite", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
               " name TEXT, value REAL);");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(NAME, "1.Do you have a car");
    cv.put(VALUE, "yes");
    db.insert(TABLE, NAME, cv);

    cv.put(NAME, "2.What is the make");
    cv.put(VALUE, "mazda");
    db.insert(TABLE, NAME, cv);

    cv.put(NAME, "3.What is the year");
    cv.put(VALUE, "2010");
    db.insert(TABLE, NAME, cv);

    cv.put(NAME, "4.What do you like about the car ");
    cv.put(VALUE, "its fast" );
    db.insert(TABLE, NAME, cv);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    android.util.Log.w("mygrades", "Upgrading database, this will destroy all data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

I have a survey in another activity and the values are to be passed from that activity to this database activity. I was thinking of passing the answers from the survey as string variables to the database and then the database can store the answers.

Is this an efficient way to do it? Or is there any other way to do this? How does a Content Provider help?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure how you meant "passing them as string variables".  What I do is create public methods in `DatabaseHelper` and use them to add records to the db from other activities.

```
public long createEventType(String eventType, String eventTypeDesc) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(EVENTTYPE_NAME, eventType);
    initialValues.put(EVENTTYPE_DESC, eventTypeDesc);
    return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(EVENTTYPE_TABLE, null, initialValues,
            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}
```

Then when I want to add this type of record from another activity I simply do this:

`mDbHelper.createEventType(title, desc);`

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know how many questions do you plan to have in the survey, how do you build the questions and if you plan to update the survey with new questions in time(or what do you do with that data you collect). A database is a good options if you plan to have more then the six questions you inserted in your code, also storing the answers as `Strings` is a good option (but it depends on how you actually build the questions).

If the number of question is really small(and don't plan to update the survey, or it's a one time survey) you could also store them in a file on the internal storage(it will be private so only your app will have access to it).

A `ContentProvider` is really useful if you intend to expose data from your app to other apps that are installed on the user phone. I doubt that you plan to expose the results of that survey to other installed apps so the `ContentProvider` shouldn't interest you.

Comment: thanks for your response , i dont htink that i will be needing a content provider as I will not be trasfering data to other apps.

Comment: The answers i have are long at all , just a few words or numbers

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city Do you plan to change this survey or you'll show it to the user only one time?

Comment: this is how its works , a user will have the option tho take the survey , after he takes the survey , we will store the data into the database , then another user can take the survey and his/her answers will be saved. So in the first listview we will have the names of all the people who took the survey , and when we click on the name , we get a view or delete option. once we view the survey ,we can see the questions and answers

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city Go with a database implementation. If you only have 12 question in the survey you could build your database like this: an `_id` column, a `name` column where you store the user name, plus 12 column each storing the answer from one of the 12 questions of the survey. When you want to show the list of users who took the survey query for the `_id` and `name` column, when you want to show the answers for a particular user then query the database for the user `_id` and return the answer columns.

Comment: cant we store an entire survey under a given user name and retrieve the survey using the user name?

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city Of course, you can query the database by username. If you want to store the entire survey results in one column you can build a string of the answer separated for example by comma `,`. When you want the values just get that string from the database and split it by `,` and you'll have an array of strings with the results.